# NullPointerException in trycatch block

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I am studying about try-catch block.
Here we throw NullPointerException by blowup()
, even we can assign

```
Exception e = new NullPointerException();
```

And BlewIt class again is a type Exception class.
so the exception we throw must be caught in  catch block, but it didn't.

```
class BlewIt extends Exception {
    BlewIt() { }
    BlewIt(String s) { super(s); }
}
class Test {
    static void blowUp() throws BlewIt {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            blowUp();
        } catch (BlewIt b) {
            System.out.println("Caught BlewIt");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Uncaught Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Uncaught Exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Test.blowUp(Test.java:7)
        at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

But if you write code like this , it is working fine :

```
try {
    blowUp();
    } catch (Exception b) {
        System.out.println("Caught BlewIt");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Uncaught Exception");
    }
```

Now BlewIt is of NullPointerException type but still i am getting same output.

```
class BlewIt extends NullPointerException {
    BlewIt() {
    }

    BlewIt(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}


class Test {
    static void blowUp() throws BlewIt {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exception e = new NullPointerException();
        try {
            blowUp();
        } catch (BlewIt b) {
            System.out.println("Caught BlewIt");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Uncaught Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me out in clearing the concept behind it.

Comment: Just because `BlewIt` is an `Exception` doesn't mean that `NullPointerException` is of type `BlewIt` - it isn't.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle thanks for the quick reply. 

Got you point.

and tried something different and added some more code.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle although BlewIt now is of NullPointerException type but still i am getting same output.

Comment: yeah bcoz i am throwing a super class , rather than sub class .... right ?

Comment: Right. In your latest example, `BlewIt` is a `NullPointerException` - but a `NullPointerException` is not a `BlewIt`. That's why it still doesn't work. You'd need to throw `BlewIt` to make it work, not the super class,

Answer (score 3):

A `NullPointerException` is not a sub-class of `BlewIt`. Therefore catching `BlewIt` doesn't catch `NullPointerException`.

If you want to catch `BlewIt`, you should `throw new BlewIt ()` in `blowUp()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing `NullPointerException` and your catch block is catching `BlewIt` so it directly goes to `finally` block and print Uncaught Exception with a stack trace of `NullPointerException`.

Your catch block will only catch exception of type `BlewIt` and its sub types.

**EDIT**

```
class BlewIt extends NullPointerException
```

This will make `BlewIt` a subclass of `NullPointerException` not vice-versa. So you will Still not be able to catch `NullPointerException` by `BlewIt`

Answer (score 1):

To put things simply, when BlewIt extends Exception, BlewIt becomes a subclass of exception, and it does not imply that it will catch NullPointerException.

```
static void blowUp() throws BlewIt {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

However since NullPointerException is not a checked Exception your code compiles.

But when you throw the NullPointer exception later in your code and try to catch it via a catch block, as expected it doesn't catch it.